# codeigniter data is not insert into database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

hello Everyone i am new in codeigniter i was try to insert data in database but not work properly.but not insert data in database.I was activate helper and auto load is i was write.

my controller

```
public function save() {
    if($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $this->Checkout_model->process();                
    }
}
```

my model

```
function process() {
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $data=array (
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'email' => $email,
        'address' => $address               
    );
    $this->db->insert('customers',$data);
}
```

Comment: What type of error is displayed

Comment: no error in display but also not save in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code In Controller

```
public function save() {
    if($this->input->post('submit')) {
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $data=array (
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'email' => $email,
        'address' => $address               
    );
        $this->Checkout_model->process($data);                
    }
}
```

In Model

```
function process($data) { 
    $this->db->insert('customers',$data);
}
```